# Add a numeric chart in StrategicERP dashboard

Tags: dynamic, statistics, analytics, dashboard

Trying to add a new numeric chart on StrategicERP dashboard. Please guide me how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made changes to numeric chart

1. can add multiple charts using multi=4
2. can add icons to individual chart

   - Go to http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp
   - Choose the icon you want for e.g. "glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"
   - Just copy briefcase
   - Now extraparams will become icon=bullhorn,briefcase,paperclip,heart-empty
3. Extraparams will become "multi=4&icon=bullhorn,briefcase,paperclip,heart-empty"
4. if you want to decrease height then it will become "multi=4&height=300&icon=bullhorn,briefcase,paperclip,heart-empty"